# private final in superclass can be overridden?

Tags: java

> Which three statements are true? (Choose three.)
>
> A. A final method in class X can be abstract if and only if X is
>   abstract.
>
> B. A protected method in class X can be overridden by any subclass of
>   X.
>
> C. A private static method can be called only within other static
>   methods in class X.
>
> D. A non-static public final method in class X can be overridden in
>   any subclass of X.
>
> E. A public static method in class X can be called by a subclass of X
>   without explicitly referencing the class X.
>
> F. A method with the same signature as a private final method in class
>   X can be implemented in a subclass of X.
>
> G. A protected method in class X can be overridden by a subclass of X
>   only if the subclass is in the same package as X.

This question is from SCJP. Answer is BEF

I understand BE but F says that method is "private final" then how subclass can overide this method because its defined as final and private method.

Please clear F point.

Comment: F doesn't say anything about overriding...

Comment: `final` cannot be overridden. moreover the very meaning of it is NOT to be overridden

Comment: Adding `non-static, non-final` to B makes it more correct!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer F isn't an example of overriding, it's an example of method scope. A method that is declared `private` in a class isn't visible to subclasses of that class, and so there's no overlap; the subclass doesn't see a method in the superclass that it can override. The subclass, with its own method `void foo(int)`, is completely unaware of the superclass's `private void foo(int)`.

Comment: That's not 'scope', that's 'visibility'. 'Scope' is determined by `{}.`

Comment: @EJP It's both not visible and out of scope, and the ability to have a duplicate of a superclass's `private final` method is a consequence. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3

Answer (score 3):

> > I understand BE but F says that method is "private final" then how subclass can overide this method because its defined as final and private method.

The question did not say anything about over-riding.  Because a private method exists only in the context of that class, it does not participate in over-riding.  You cannot over-ride a private method because private methods are not visible from outside of the class that defines them anyway.

Another way to look at is is that they are two unrelated methods and their signatures being identical is sheer coincidence.

Because a private method in a child-class is not over-riding a private method in a super class, the `final` keyword has no effect.

Comment: I know it was just a Java test question, but it is a bad practice to have a method with the same name and signature as a private method in super-class. Cause changing visibility of parent class' method in future, can cause problems (then it will become overriding!).

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh Not necessarily. The whole point of having `private` members is that the subclass shouldn't be aware of the existence of the member. In the most common versioning scheme, major.minor.micro, adding visible methods like that would cause an increment in the minor version, and minor-version upgrades are expected to require changes to classes that subclass or implement types in the library.